# Bcrypt hash password is not the same of password hash saved in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, hash, bcrypt

I'm using bcrypt.hash in a password, and this hash normal... but when i save this hashed password in a mongodb with a mongoose, this not the same passowrd when i hash the password.

Example:

password hash: $2b$10$bUY/7mrZd3rp1S7NwaZko.ShDFj47rAfdGHG1QcQxGdtvzaDd.WH2

password saved mongo: $2b$10$fOLYjjib7ycRbq7BqzNdMuPNbTPjMIVAZ1QQzBvX5cMEhi6rERjJK

My signup user code:

```
req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const user = await User.create(req.body);
    Logs.logRequest(item.path, { item });
    user.password = undefined;

    return res.status(201).send({
        user,
        token: await createToken(user),
});
```

My login user code:

```
const passOk = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!passOk) {
    Logs.logError(item.path, {
        ...item,
        error: "Error",
});
```

My password in user schema:

```
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    select: false,
},
```

When i compare, the password always not equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because my User model have a pre.("save") with bcrypt hash, and this conflicting with bcrypt hash in router.js

Comment: what ? can you elaborate ? 
as for mine, I had saved a password using node bcrypt and now with python bcrypt and im getting different hashed password format.  Ones with `$asasdad` format and ones with `BinData(0,$asdasd)` not sure, its the same library but they are being stored differently (format wise)

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me. The reason is storing functions having the same name. I removed the rest and it worked fine for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).